# Hive: Add a column with a value repeated of a specific columnn in a specific row?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in Hive that looks like this called `Products`.

```
'Root Product | Product | Date 
     A            A       2012
     A            B       2013
     A            C       2013 
     D            D       2014 
     D            E       2015
```

Is it possible to add fourth column repeating the value of the date present in the column `Date` when `Root Product == Product` (the date of the root product)? Such that

```
'Root Product | Product | Date | Root Date
     A            A       2012     2012
     A            B       2013     2012
     A            C       2013     2012
     D            D       2014     2014
     D            E       2015     2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `max` window function.

```
select root_product
      ,product
      ,date
      ,max(case when root_product = product then date end) over(partition by root_product) as root_date
from tbl
```